# creating test1 and test2 files in /var directory in Linux,

Tags: linux, files, symlink, hard-link

I need to create test1 and test2 files in /var directory in Linux , and creating Hard link for test1 file and soft link for test2 file in /tmp

Comment: Perhaps you could show what you already know (or have learned) and what you tried, and what the results were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
touch /var/file1 /var/file2
```

This will create `file1` and `file2` in `/var` directory.

```
ln /var/file1 /tmp/hard_link_to_file1
```

This will create hard link to `file1` in `/tmp` directory.

```
ln -s /var/file2 /tmp/symbolic_link_to_file2
```

This will create symbolic link to `file2` in `/tmp` directory.